# Error: The parameter 'event' of the method 'AlwaysWinPanGestureRecognizer.addAllowedPointer' has type

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am having the below error after installing **html_editor_enhanced: ^2.2.0+1-dev.1** in flutter

```
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_colorpicker-0.5.0/lib/src/hsv_picker.dart:730:43: Error: The parameter 'event' of the method 'AlwaysWinPanGestureRecognizer.addAllowedPointer' has type 'PointerDownEvent', which does not match the corresponding type, 'PointerEvent', in the overridden method, 'DragGestureRecognizer.addAllowedPointer'.
 - 'PointerDownEvent' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/events.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/events.dart').
 - 'PointerEvent' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/events.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/events.dart').
Change to a supertype of 'PointerEvent', or, for a covariant parameter, a subtype.
  void addAllowedPointer(PointerDownEvent event) {
                                          ^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/monodrag.dart:256:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('addAllowedPointer').
  void addAllowedPointer(PointerEvent event) {
       ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

What could be the solution?

I was following [html_editor_enhanced](https://pub.dev/packages/html_editor_enhanced/example)
tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html_editor_enhanced dev here. To fix this, you can either upgrade to the new Flutter stable version (2.5.0) or use the instructions found here: https://github.com/tneotia/html-editor-enhanced/issues/68#issuecomment-863369808.